# Using jQuery selector on AJAX returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slide

I am a beginner with jQuery, and am stuck with this problem:

I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3" class="xtra"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>    
</table>
```

And I want to hide/unhide the particular rows with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td[colspan=3]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
            $target.slideUp();
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
        }                    
    });
});
```

Using this approach directly works, but I am loading this table HTML using AJAX, and thus the selectors don't work. How should I modify my selectors?

I'm loading this HTML with this:

```
$.get('/tab.html',function(data){
        $('#tabContentBox').html(data);
                 ...
                 ...
}
```

Comment: is your table generated dynamically.

Comment: yes, table is generated dynamically from the database.

Comment: Then musa's answer should work. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegating the event is what you need to do

```
$('#tabContentBox').on("click","table",function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
        $target.slideUp();
    } else {
        $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
    }                    
});
```

Comment: Yes, the toggle works now, but not as expected.
But that tr needs to be hidden on page load.

Comment: @user2006190 I suggest using css for that, if not you'll have to hide them in the callback of you `$.get` call.

Comment: @user2006190 try `td[colspan=3] p{display:none;}`

Comment: Oh, I was using display:none for td, and not for p. *smacked myself* 
:-) Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("td[colspan=3]").find("p").hide();
$(document).on('click', 'table', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
        $target.slideUp();
    } else {
        $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
    }                    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: All of these examples contain a defect which causes expanded section to disappear when you double-click on it while it's minimized.

The defect comes from code in this if:
if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('/tab.html' , function(data){$('#tabContentBox').html(data)})
.done(function(data) {
   $(#tabContentBox).on("click","table",function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
var $target = $(event.target);
if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
    $target.slideUp();
} else {
    $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
}
```

});
     });

Answer (score 0):

how could do same for the below table.
where a click should hide the details table.

@model Tuple

@{  ViewBag.Title = "Your Active Jobs"; }

```
 <h2>Tool tracker</h2>

 <table id= "master">
 <tr style="background-color:Blue">
 <td></td>
 <td><font color="white">ScanCode</font></td>
 <td><font color="white">Description</font></td>
 <td><font color="white">Type</font></td>
 <td><font color="white">Date Out</font></td>
 <td><font color="white"> Date In</font></td>
 <td><font color="white">Responsible Employee</font></td>
 <td><font color="white">Charge Type</font></td>
 <td><font color="white">Qty</font></td>
 <td><font color="white">Rate</font></td>
 <td><font color="white">Charges to Date</font></td>
 <td><font color="white">Replacement Charges</font></td>
 <td><font color="white"> Status</font></td>
 </tr>

 @foreach (var j in Model.Item1)
 {
     //Master table
    <tr style="background-color:#ADD8E6">
    <td><b>+</b></td>
    <td><p><font color="black">@j.JobId</font></p></td>
    <td colspan="8"><p><font color="black">@j.Name-@j.ManagerName</font></p></td>
    <td><p><font color="black">@j.ChargesToDate</font></p></td>
    <td><p><font color="black">@j.ReplacementCharges</font></p></td>
    <td><p><font color="black">@j.JobStatus</font></p></td>
    </tr>
     //details table

     foreach (var d in Model.Item2.Where(t => t.JobId == j.JobId))
     {   <tr><table>
         <tr id = "details">
         <td colspan="0"></td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.Scancode</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.Description</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.Type</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.DateOut</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.DateIn</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.ResponsibleEmployee</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.ChargeType</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.Quantity</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.Rate</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.ChargesToDate</td>
         <td colspan="0">@d.ReplacementCharges</td>
         <td colspan="0"></td>
         </tr></table></tr>
     }
 }

 </table>
```